# For loop a square pattern of numbers

Tags: python

In this question I had to create a program that prompts the user for a number and then prompt again for how many rows to create. Something like:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

This is what I came up with and I have tried many different ways to get the same result but it didn't work.

```
num=int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 10: "))
rows=int(input("Enter how many rows to of numbers: "))
for i in range(num):
    print(i,end=" ")
for x in range(rows):
    print (x)
```

This is the output I came up with:

```
Enter a number between 1 and 10: 6
Enter how many rows to of numbers: 4
0 1 2 3 4 5 0
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may simply do it like:

```
num = 5
rows = 4
for i in range(1, num+1):
    print('{} '.format(i) * rows)
```

Output:

```
1 1 1 1 
2 2 2 2 
3 3 3 3 
4 4 4 4 
5 5 5 5
```

*Explanation:* When you multiply a `str` with some number say `n`, new string is returned with original string repeated `n` times. Doing this you will eliminate your nested loop

Comment: But I still needs to prompt the user

Comment: It is demo code. I hard coded `num` and `rows`.  In your code use the value of `input()` which you are doing currently. Just replace the logic of my `for` loop.

Comment: Instead of using the range(1, num+1), just use i+1 inside the for loop.

Comment: @Jonas: What is the benefit of that? `range(1, num+1)` is cleaner.

Comment: @anonymous range(num) is the pythonic way and I would say much more aesthetic.

Comment: @anonymous It also helps if the same loop is later used to loop through arrays - keeping loops zero-indexed is generally best practice.

Comment: @Jonas: Can you provide me ANY document that says `range(num)` is more *Pythonic* than `range(1, num+1)`? Also I would like to know the definition of your *Pythonic* term. And why will I call my loop from 0th index when I wanted to start it from 1 ? Suppose you want to print numbers from `100` to `200`. Will you do `range(100)` and use `i` like `i+100`. Really?

Comment: @Jonas: And how could the same loop be used with the arrays (to be more precise `list`)? It would be a different loop in that case (this loop is used with `range()`). I really do not know what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: Just use nested for loops:

```
num = int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 10: "))
rows = int(input("Enter how many rows to of numbers: "))
for i in range(num):
    print ('\n')
    for x in range(rows):
        print (i + 1)
```

The code above will go through the range 0 to num, printing first a new line and then printing the current number rows times.

Answer (score 0):

```
rows = 5
side = int(input("Please Enter any Side of a Square  : "))
for i in range(side):
    for j in range(side):
        if(i == 0 or i == side - 1 or j == 0 or j == side - 1):
            print(i, end = '  ')
        else:
            print(i, end = '  ')
    print()
```